# How to add rule file into /etc/udev/rules.d in NixOS?

Tags: linux, udev, nixos

I'm following this instruction: https://github.com/nns779/px4_drv

`make` under the directory `fwtool` builds `it930x-firmware.bin` and `make` under `driver` builds `px4_drv` kernel module.

Now `it930x.nix` and `px4_drv.nix` is here.

https://gist.github.com/gtgteq/30cb73c344477d26f8c69768e010331a

`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-px4video.rules` of `px4_drv` is not show in system.

How to make available this rule file?

Comment: In your `configuration.nix` try `services.udev.packages = [ px4_drv ]`. You may also need to change the udev path in the `installPhase` to `$out/lib/udev/rules.d`

Comment: Your comment should be promoted to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following Emmanuel's two instructions, my gist is updated.

In your configuration.nix, try

```
services.udev.packages = [ px4_drv ]
```

You may also need to change the udev path in the installPhase to `$out/lib/udev/rules.d`, not `$out/etc/udev/rules.d`.